# What is wrong with my code about Model bind in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to make 3 dropdown lists for date entering. After submit, `BindModel` method in `IModelBinder` combines day, month and year to one type. My problem is missing data, controller receives a new "testday"

```
public class DateAndTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        int day, month, year;
        day = int.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".day").AttemptedValue);
        month = int.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".month").AttemptedValue);
        year = int.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".year").AttemptedValue);
        DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        TestDay tday = new TestDay();
        tday.Day2T = date;
        return tday;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID, Day2T.day, Day2T.day.month")]TestDay testday)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TestDays.Add(testday);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(testday);
    }
```

Html code:

```
<div class="col-md-10">

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day2T.Day, Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }), "Day")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Day2T.Day)

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day2T.Month, Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i) }), "Month")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Day2T.Month)

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day2T.Year, Enumerable.Range(1900, 117).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }), "Year")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Day2T.Year)@**@
</div>
```

Comment: Its kind of hard to read but it looks like your not binding correctly.. Can you show is your interface ? `IModelBinder` also your BindModel looks like a method.. Not a class model.. also you have an object return type but you are returning strongly typed `return tday;` from it.. Any reason for this ? Its quite confusing what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'd go with good old viewModels,

Comment: I trying to do "date of birth from 3 dropdownlist to DateTime" (http://forums.asp.net/t/1638300.aspx?date+of+birth+from+3+dropdownlist+to+DateTime) and do following http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx.
So i try to make but it fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem have been fixed. I want post for newbies can be find answer if they have same problems.
I forgot post code in Global.asax.cs

> ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateAndTimeModelBinder());

I remove [Bind(Include = "ID, Day2T.day, Day2T.day.month")] in controller.

```
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ID,Day2T")] TestDay testday)
```

And change return in BindModel function:

```
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ...
        DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        ...
        return date;
    }
```